# Flask how to redirect @login_required to specific route?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am building a small web application as a project and i am using the decorator `@login_required` at the moment it redirects to an unexisting route `/login` how can i manually set the route?

This is my code:

```
@auth.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop("user", None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flask-login` to handle user sessions.

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install flask-login && pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Add this package to your application instance. This is either the `__init__.py` file or the file that has:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is how you add it:

```py
# __init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes
```

I have passed the `login` view function to the `login` object. This function is the one that handles user logins.

```py
from app import app
from flask_login import login_required


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Your code
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

I have passed the `login_required` decorator to the `index()` view function. Every time a user want to access the index page, they will be redirected to the *login* page for authentication, which is rendered by the `login` view function. After a successful login, only then will this person access the index page.

Feel free to pass the `login_required` decorator to any other function that can be anonymously accessed. I have seen that you are using blueprints. My example does not make use of blueprints, though it should be fairly easy for you to update the code to use your blueprints.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which library you were using, so I'm assuming it's a package that contains Flask Login. You can alter the login view by changing the config value for the `login_manager.login_view` as seen [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#customizing-the-login-process)